# validating Logstash configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, logstash

I am trying to validate my logstash configuration.

Using :

`sudo -u logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings -t -f /etc/logstash/conf.d`

I received the following error:

> penJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is
>   expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of
>   parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
>   WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in
>   $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using
>   --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /tmp/hsperfdata_logstash/-t/log4j2.properties.
>   Using default config which logs errors to the console [INFO ]
>   2018-10-09 14:56:50.240 [main] scaffold - Initializing module
>   {:module_name=>"fb_apache",
>   :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
>   [INFO ] 2018-10-09 14:56:50.265 [main] scaffold - Initializing module
>   {:module_name=>"netflow",
>   :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"} [INFO
>   ] 2018-10-09 14:56:50.378 [main] writabledirectory - Creating
>   directory {:setting=>"path.queue",
>   :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"} [INFO ] 2018-10-09
>   14:56:50.380 [main] writabledirectory - Creating directory
>   {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue",
>   :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"} [WARN ]
>   2018-10-09 14:56:51.099 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the
>   'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are
>   specified [INFO ] 2018-10-09 14:56:51.126 [LogStash::Runner] agent -
>   No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID
>   {:uuid=>"80207611-d5b8-47dd-b229-23c2ade385ae",
>   :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"} [INFO ] 2018-10-09
>   14:56:51.568 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Starting Logstash
>   {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.4"} [INFO ] 2018-10-09 14:56:52.021 [Api
>   Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint
>   {:port=>9600} [ERROR] 2018-10-09 14:56:53.586 [Ruby-0-Thread-1:
>   /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22]
>   beats - Invalid setting for beats input plugin:
>
> input {
>       beats {
>         # This setting must be a path
>         # File does not exist or cannot be opened /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
>         ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
>         ...
>       }   } [ERROR] 2018-10-09 14:56:53.588 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22]
>   beats - Invalid setting for beats input plugin:
>
> input {
>       beats {
>         # This setting must be a path
>         # File does not exist or cannot be opened /etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key
>         ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
>         ...
>       }   } [ERROR] 2018-10-09 14:56:53.644 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22]
>   agent - Failed to execute action
>   {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
>   :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is
>   wrong with your configuration.",
>   :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:89:in
>   `config_init'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inputs/base.rb:62:in`
>   initialize'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/plugins/plugin_factory.rb:89:in
>   `plugin'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:112:in`
>   plugin'", "(eval):8:in `<eval>'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:994:in`
>   eval'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:84:in
>   `initialize'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in`
>   initialize'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in
>   `execute'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in`block
>   in converge_state'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in
>   `with_pipelines'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in`block
>   in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in`
>   converge_state'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in `block
>   in converge_state_and_update'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in`
>   with_pipelines'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in
>   `converge_state_and_update'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in`
>   execute'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in
>   `block in execute'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in`
>   block in initialize'"]}

I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check logstash.yml file available on /etc/logstash ? If it available  stop the logstash service and kill if any processes ruining on background. Save your config file on /etc/logstash/conf.d/your_file.conf. To run the config test go to, logstash bin directory and run

```
./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/your_config_file.conf --config.test_and_exit
```